# How to pragmatically open the popup extension from background.js

Tags: javascript, json, html, css

If any idea then please share with me,

**I am trying to open the popup extension from background.js** so that if anything happens in Background.js then my browser action popup will automatically show in my current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to open just a new window and not any extension but here is something you can try

```
function clickme(){
    var url = "popup.html";
    var windowName = "extension_popup";
    newwindow=window.open(url,windowName,'width=300, height=400, status=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: where should I add this click me function in my extension ( Background.js or content.js) or I don't wanna click on my extension I want it automatically on any event in my background.js.

Comment: what is your background.js ?

Comment: ******************  Manifest File **************     {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "NONE",
      "short_name": "nonoe",
      "description": "This extension use for none",
      "version": "1.1",
      "content_scripts": [{
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
      }],
      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": true
      },
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
  }

Comment: in manifest, I declare my background.js file which will always be active and in-browser action I attach my popup.html extension.

Comment: I follow the same Kirankumar Dafda.

Comment: You need to get an event call first in any function. or add any event handler for background.js

Comment: I have an event call function in my background.js but I don't have any idea if a call is in that function then how popup browser extension will automatically show in the current page @Kirankumar Dafda.

Comment: Kirankumar Dafda

Comment: I just mentioned how to open pop up on your screen, now to implement it into your background.js you have to find events from it.